# What is the most concise way to display a changing value with Combine and SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I am trying to wrap my head around SwiftUI and Combine. I want to keep some text in the UI up-to-date with a value. In this case, it's the battery level of the device, for example.

Here is my code. First of all, it seems like this is quite a bit of code to achieve what I want to do, so I'm wondering if I may be able to do without some of it. Also, this code used to run over the summer, but now it crashes, probably due to changes in SwiftUI and Combine.

How can this be fixed to work with the current version of SwiftUI and Combine? And, is it possible to cut back on the amount of code here to do the same thing?

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var batteryLevelPublisher = UIDevice.current
        .publisher(for: \.batteryLevel)
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)

    lazy var batteryLevelSubscriber = Subscribers.Assign(object: self,
                                                         keyPath: \.batteryLevel)

    var batteryLevel: Float = UIDevice.current.batteryLevel {
        didSet {
            willChange.send()
        }
    }

    init() {
        batteryLevelPublisher.subscribe(batteryLevelSubscriber)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(Int(round(viewModel.batteryLevel * 100)))%")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimal working example to be pasted inside iPadOS Swift playground.

Basically it’s the give code aligned with the latest changes from SwiftUI and Combine.

- use the @Published property wrapper for any properties you want to observe in your view (Docs: By default an ObservableObject synthesizes an objectWillChange publisher that emits the changed value before any of its @Published properties changes.). This avoids the usage of custom setters and objectWillChange.
- the cancellable is the output from Publishers.Assign, it can be used to cancel the subscription manually and for best practice, it will be stored in a “CancellableBag” thus cancel the subscription on deinit. This practice is inspired by other reactive frameworks such as RxSwift and ReactiveUI.
- I found without turning on the battery level notifications the KVO publisher for battery level will emit just once -1.0.

```
// iPadOS playground
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

class BatteryModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var level = UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    init () {
        UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
        assignLevelPublisher()
    }

    private func assignLevelPublisher() {
        _ = UIDevice.current
            .publisher(for: \.batteryLevel)
            .assign(to: \.level, on: self)
            .store(in: &self.cancellableSet)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var batteryModel = BatteryModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(Int(round(batteryModel.level * 100)))%")
    }
}

let host = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = host
```

Comment: I thought it would be better to keep the publisher logic out of a ContentView and in the ViewModel, with all the data coming through the ObservedObject. Is it possible to use a similar approach and do that? I can't seem to figure out how I can use `.assign` for a property on the Observable Object.

Comment: Thank you for the update to use a model! Even if you don't think the explanation of basic concepts would fit here, I would appreciate if you could add any links to the answer that you think would help explain it. I have ready a lot of Apple's documentation, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around the concepts without understanding why certain things are used in specific examples. For example, I don't understand what `.store` and `cancellableSet` are doing here. I would have thought I could just use `.assign` to update the `level` var.

Comment: Why are `.store` and `cancellableSet` necessary here? Why can't `.assign` be used to update the `level` var?

Comment: I suppose `assign` returns `AnyCancelable` which has to be stored somewhere since it automatically unsubscribes on deinit

Comment: @BenSinclair I find that if the `.store` is not used, the code in assign only works once. Any more explanation on this?

Comment: @Colin `AnyCancellable` cancels the subscription on `deinit`, so you have to store it somewhere to keep receiving the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generalizable solution that will work for any object that supports KVO:

```
class KeyPathObserver<T: NSObject, V>: ObservableObject {
  @Published var value: V
  private var cancel = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  init(_ keyPath: KeyPath<T, V>, on object: T) {
    value = object[keyPath: keyPath]
    object.publisher(for: keyPath)
      .assign(to: \.value, on: self)
      .store(in: &cancel)
  }
}
```

So to monitor the battery level (for example) in your view you'd add an `@ObservedObject` like this

```
@ObservedObject batteryLevel = KeyPathObserver(\.batteryLevel, on: UIDevice.current)
```

And then you can access the value either directly or via the `@ObservedObject`'s `value` property

```
batteryLevel.value
```